# an alternate way to get all products from dynamic array?

Tags: solidity, arrays

I'm newbie with Solidity and trying to make some smart contract for eCommerce :D basically.

Here is code of that:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract ecommerce{

    event OnProductAdd(uint, string, uint);
    event UserInfo(User);

    struct User{
        address _address;
        bytes32 name;
        uint balance;
    }

    struct Product{
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint price;
    } 

    address _owner;

    mapping(address => User) public user;

    Product[] public products;

    modifier isAdmin() {
        require(msg.sender == _owner, "you don't have admin access");
        _;
    }

    constructor() public {
        _owner = msg.sender; 
    } 

    function addProduct(uint _id, string _name, uint _price) isAdmin public {

        products.push(Product({
            id: _id,
            name : _name,
            price : _price
        }));

        emit OnProductAdd(_id, _name, _price);
    }

    function getAllProducts() view public{

       //TODO: return all products 
    }

}
```

Now, what I want is to get all products, but it's a dynamic array..and we cannot return dynamic array directly in Solidity. 
So, what alternate way I can use to get all products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, I think that this is the best that you can do:

```
function getProduct(uint index) external view returns (uint, string, uint) {
    Product storage product = products[index];
    return (product.id, product.name, product.price);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that I saw with many answers, but it will return only one product, index pass by user.

Comment: "Get All" seems like a natural thing to do in a database-centric world. _In my opinion_, you need to reconsider the flows so it isn't necessary. For example, any client who wishes to see them all can do so by watching your `OnProductAdd` log. They can check their own off-chain assessment of the situation with the suggested single row getter. If a client has a complete and verifiable copy of the state, what need is there for a `Get All` function? Bear in mind that one must design everything for consistent gas cost at any scale - O(1), so linear increases are not acceptable.

Comment: @HinaKhuman: I agree with the comment above. Most likely you don't need a the entire array - neither in your on-chain (Solidity) code nor in your off-chain code. So you might want to review the way that you are using this contract and check whether or not it is really imperative to return the entire array to anyone outside of this contract.

Comment: @goodvibration: I've little bit confusion for `storage` and `memory`, like in the answer you've used `Product storage product`, instead if I use `Product memory product`, the result remains the same, so, any difference between both except gas cost(i.e 10 gas change in this case)?

Comment: @HinaKhuman: As far as I understand, `storage` creates a reference on the stack, while `memory` creates a copy on the stack. The latter is slightly more expensive, and can also lead to insufficient stack-size (compilation error) in some cases. So use `memory` if you need a local copy which you can change later on without changing the original array, and use `storage` in any other case (i.e., if you want to change the global array, or if you need to do read-only operations).